# How intensively has FvD campaigned for or against The Netherlands exiting the EU?

Tags: european-union, netherlands

In the 2019 provincial elections, Forum voor Democratie (FVD) is set to win the most seats in the Dutch Senate (see picture from the Dutch broadcaster [NOS](https://nos.nl/liveblog/2276959-nieuwe-prognose-forum-voor-democratie-de-grootste-met-13-zetels.html) below).

[image]

I haven't really followed their campaign, but it seems that there is some confusion over whether the party is in favour of a so-called Nexit (Netherlands Exit of the EU) or not. To quote [the Volkskrant from the 21st of February 2019](https://www.volkskrant.nl/nieuws-achtergrond/baudet-corrigeert-partijgenoot-forum-voor-democratie-wil-wel-een-nexit-~b8909052/):

> Forum voor Democratie (FvD) blijft een hartstochtelijk voorstander van een vertrek van Nederland uit de Europese Unie. Partijleider Thierry Baudet keert zich tegen de bewering van Eerste Kamer-lijsttrekker Henk Otten dat de partij ‘helemaal niet per se voor een Nexit is’. ‘In die uitspraak herken ik me niet’, zegt Baudet.

Translated (by me):

> Forum voor Democracy (FvD) remains a strong supporter of a Dutch exit from the European Union. Party leader Thierry Baudet distances himself from the claim by its front-runner for the Senate, Henk Otten, that the party isn't 'in favour of Next per se'. 'I don't see it that way', Baudet said.

Seeing how Baudet is the centerpiece around which the party seems to revolve, his view carries a lot of weight. On the other hand, he was not up for election, but the front-runner for the Senate said almost the opposite.

My question is how FvD campaigned. Did they actively campaign in favour of Nexit? The party is very active on social media and they organise a lot of meetings, how central of a topic was the idea of The Netherlands leaving the European Union?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the campaign for this election, emphasis was placed on FvD's opposition to the Climate Deal made by the government, which promises to spend heaps of money on a unmeasurable temperature reduction.

This was in line with the general news in the Netherlands in the months leading to the elections. There was lots of news about rising energy costs - due to additional taxes - the costs of Climate Deal, and so on.

---

That said, FvD's point of view on the EU is clear. quoting their [site about their views on the EU](https://forumvoordemocratie.nl/standpunten/europese-unie):

> Het is tijd om te stoppen met de muntunie en de open grenzen, en daarna de EU te verlaten. We willen samenwerken en handel drijven – en dat kan uitstekend via de Europese Vrijhandelsassociatie, eventueel via lidmaatschap van de Europese Economische Ruimte, en uiteraard via tal van andere internationale verdragen. Maar de EU, de open grenzen en de euro: daar moeten we vanaf.

Roughly translated by me as:

> It's time to quit the monetary union and the open borders, followed by leaving the EU. We want cooperation and trade - which is possible through the European Free Trade Association, optionally through the European Economical Area, and of course through many other international treaties. However, the EU, open borders and the euro: we must get rid of those.

---

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's as authoritative an answer as we're going to get. I wouldn't say it's that clear though, their front-runner for the Senate either didn't know or disagreed (by saying his party isn't in favour of Nexit 'per se').

Comment: @JJJ In my opinion, it's a remark about his personal views made by a less experienced politician. Which was exploited by his political opponents, which are supported by the paper mentioned (de Volkskrant), to suggest a divide in the new party.

Comment: Well there are multiple sources quoting him as not fully committing on the Nexit thing. According to [the AD](https://www.gelderlander.nl/politiek/hoe-henk-otten-uit-de-schaduw-van-thierry-baudet-stapte~a2891bd6/), he also said 'the word Nexit' isn't even in their election program. But yes, I agree this seems to be his personal opinion rather than the party line.